# Handling msg for fitting

Tags: fitting

I have a trivial question: I do Monte Carlo with some curve fitting.
Now always when a random run creates a complex fitting solution it should write 1 in a Matrix. How can I handle such msgs in a module? Thanks Walter

ADD:
Well, this is still in progress. But when I make a fit and the fitting is not real then I get a red Warning messsage. How Can I handle this msgs so that, when I get such a non proper fit (as of the random input data for the model) I would write to a list a 1. Finally after 1000 RUns I can count this 1s and get the info how many non-proper fits according due the random input data for the model I have got. Hope I could express what I am meaning. Thanks –

Add2:
It would be a idea if for the findfit fn, I could ask for the number of interations. If interations = MXINTERATIONS (f.e. 1000) then I see that it could not convergate. So I could abort the findfit and write 1 in the list. Could be this a solution? –

---

Well I have done this in that way:

```
calcMethod[randFN_, randfacdef_, samplerun_] := 
Module[{limit, vmaxmod, kmmod, yy0, xx, yy, data, datalb, dataeh, 
datahw, minxlb, maxxlb, minylb, maxylb, minx, miny, maxx, maxy, 
minxeh, minyeh, maxxeh, maxyeh, minxhw, maxxhw, minyhw, maxyhw, 
vmaxnl, kmnl, vmaxlb, kmlb, vmaxeh, kmeh, vmaxhw, kmhw, mmenten, 
eadieh, hanesw, mmentenmax, fit, rand = randFN, 
randfac = randfacdef, errflagnl},


vmaxmod = 20.0; kmmod = 1.0;
(* Print["Ideal model:   vmax = ",vmaxmod,",     km = ",kmmod]; *)


 limit = 3.*kmmod;
 xx = {limit, limit/2, limit/4, limit/8, limit/16, limit/32};
 mmentenmax = 32/limit;
 (*  rand=RandomReal[{-1.,2.},6]; *)
 (* rand=randFN; *)
 yy0 = vmaxmod*xx/(kmmod + xx);
 yy = vmaxmod*xx/(kmmod + xx) + rand*randfac;

 data = {xx, yy}\[Transpose]; minx = Min[xx]; maxx = Max[xx]; 
 miny = Min[yy]; maxy = Max[yy];
 datalb = {1/xx, 1/yy}\[Transpose]; minxlb = Min[1/xx]; 
 maxxlb = Max[1/xx]; minylb = Min[1/yy]; maxylb = Max[1/yy];
 dataeh = {yy/xx, yy}\[Transpose]; minxeh = Min[yy/xx]; 
 maxxeh = Max[yy/xx]; minyeh = Min[yy]; maxyeh = Max[yy];
 datahw = {xx, xx/yy}\[Transpose]; minxhw = Min[xx]; 
 maxxhw = Max[xx]; minyhw = Min[xx/yy]; maxyhw = Max[xx/yy];
 (* Print["yy data: ",yy]; *)
 fit = Check[
  FindFit[data, {u*x/(v + x) (*,{0<v<2*kmmod} *) }, {u, v}, x], 1, 
  FindFit::cvmit];
 (* fit=FindFit[data,{u*x/(v+x),{0<v<2*kmmod}},{u,v},x]; *)
 If[ (ToString[fit] != "1") , errflagnl = 0 , errflagnl = 1];
 vmaxnl = u /. fit;
 kmnl = v /. fit;

 (*Print["Nonlinear fit: vmax = ",vmaxnl,", km = ",kmnl];*)

 ResMetVecpRun = 
  Transpose[{{"Methodname", "Vmax Model", "km Model", 
   "vmax Methode", "km Methode", "minimum x", "maximum x", 
   "minimum y", "maximum y", 
   "ERROR-FLAG"}, {"Method 1 (Run:" <> ToString[samplerun] <> ")",
    vmaxmod, kmmod, vmaxnl, kmnl, minx, maxx, miny, maxy, 
   errflagnl}}];



  ResMetVecpRun // TraditionalForm
 ];
```

TO call:

```
ResMetVec = 
Table[calcMethod[RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, 6], 5., i ], {i, 1, 
maxSampleRuns}];
```

and the SUMs:

```
ResMetVec // MatrixForm
Print["Number of non-convergent FITs (Methode 1):", 
Sum[ResMetVec[[i]][[1]][[10]][[2]], {i, 1, maxSampleRuns}]];
```

Any recommendations? Advices are very wellcome.
thanks

Comment: Welcome! Cold you elaborate on your problem? At the moment the question is unclear.  Adding sample and input / output is usually helpful, too.

Comment: @YvesKlett Well, this is still in progress. But when I make a fit and the fitting is not real then I get a red Warning messsage. How Can I handle this msgs so that, when I get such a non proper fit (as of the random input data for the model) I would write to a list a 1. Finally after 1000 RUns I can count this 1s and get the info how many non-proper fits according due the random input data for the model I have got. Hope I could express what I am meaning. Thanks

Comment: It would be a idea if for the findfit fn, I could ask for the number of interations. If interations = MXINTERATIONS (f.e. 1000) then I see that it could not convergate. So I could abort the findfit and write 1 in the list. Could be this a solution?

Comment: Please update the question with that info, which will help getting better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Check[]` function to handle exceptions that throw messages. In detail, however, I would say that the problem is not well defined.

Comment: Yes as it is still in progress. I would be happy when I have some code to ask here once more, if there is still something unclear. Thanks But thanks for that info. CHeck could be useful.

Comment: Surely you can update your question. Actually you should, as the question is not very clear. As Yves Klett pointed out, you should present some code or concepts in a simplified version. The idea would be to avoid the messages in the first place, hence, not needing `Check[]`.

Comment: well as the data for the model is random, I think you cant avoid the CHECK, as it is done for Monte Carlo. There can be bad conditions so there is no good fit at all.

Comment: @walter-schrabmair First of all it seems to me that the code you show, contains plenty of stuff beyond a minimum working example. Anyway, here some comments. You should use `Return[]` to return your result. Use `TraditionalForm` in displaying later but not on the return value; that makes it easier to work with the output. Finally, it seems that you have an error message due to max iterations. What about increasing the `MaxIteration` of `FindFit[]`?

Comment: Thanks for that info, Yes I had to spend 2 hrs to find that it is better to use TraditionalForm later. I was a little bit confused with the different Forms. Well the fitting is ok, as even  for large iterations there will be no fit at all as the randomnumbers for the model input data will not be a valid sample set. Tho handle this I have used Check[] and write a ERRORFLAG in the matrix. After the total MC runs are done, I will delete the MC run with the Errorflag true. Thanks anyway for your info.

Comment: @walter-schrabmair Looking at the data that produces the error I also notice that this falls into a local gradient with `v` and `u` negative. You already played with conditions. In my case setting `u>0, v>0` helps. Can you assume this? You also might want to play with the `Method` settings of `FindFit[]`. In any case you could put you flagging into the `Check[]`, multiple commands should be possible, if separated by `;`. By this you avoid this strange `ToString[]` statement; while it should work perfectly fine, it looks twisted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, I can improve. I will consider your advices and thank you very much ! Yes I could assume that u and v should be pos.